# Securing access to Windows Server 2008 Application Server with Multiple Users

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

This is how my application server is set up

```
[client] ----\ _________
              /         \
[client] ----(    LAN    )---[Application Server]---[Database Server]
              \_________/
[client] ----/

1st tier                           2nd tier             3rd tier
```

We currently have applications servers running as a single user with a single password with a GUI interface.
I want to be able to have multiple people remotely login as this user to have access the applications that are running. But I want to be able to see who is logging in so that I can audit who logged in at what time. What is the best way of being able to allow multiple users to access the same desktop?  This does not occur simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

There is none - same desktop kills everything. The best you could do is RDP and then having people watch a session, that is shared, but that has a problem with control. Basically your approach of what an app server is is like 30 years behind the curve - and runs straight against how MS says things should be done.

An App should not run on a desktop for a server. Simple like that. But as a service. With control applications that possibly also can remote log into the app. Look at how all MS software does it. Running an app in a server on a desktop is where you go so far away from best practices that it then comes back and bites you.

Comment: This is just wrong; see my answer.  (Well, I do agree that this is a bad way to set up an application server, but saying it's not possible, or has to be done over a shared RDP session is not correct.)

Comment: @HopelessN00b that gives you a nice indication who logged on, but how do you ensure they get the same desktop?

Comment: Can you please provide how applications should be run. An article to Microsoft would help. Instead of bashing you can give me suggestions.

Comment: Well, I may suggest you start this by reading my answer. I clearly state how things should be programmed. And it is not bashing. You violate windows design guidelines then ask for a way to fix that by violating remote desktop design principles - sadly the later won't work. Just won't work.

Comment: Well, that's what I want to avoid. As I don't write the applications. I just administer them. Thanks though

Comment: Sadly that is all that is there. We left the time of "running servers on the desktop" 20 years ago or so. It still happens, but then people normally skip the security aspect (shared password, using one account etc.). Heck, if even happens in high risk scenarios. But there sadly is no way to make it nice.

Comment: @TomTom As I mentioned in your comments to my answer, you still log the IP of the connecting computer, so long as the RDP sessions are disconnected, rather than logged off, meeting all the requirements of the OP's question.

Comment: The cmputer is not the person. Damn, if you eve have to work in a secure network yuo realize that IP is bull. Can be changed, unless one üputs a LOT of infrastructure in place to do ethernet level authentication. "Who" is not IP, it is a username/password combo, minimum.